# what is the type signature for "return Nothing"?

Tags: haskell, monads

In [the chapter 14 of Real World Haskell (Monads)](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html), the type signature of the inject function `return` is `return :: a -> m a`, where `m a` is a type constructor, so under ghci I can specify a type signature for a `return arg1`, such as:

```
*Main> return 1 :: Maybe Integer
Just 1

*Main> return "ok" :: Maybe String
Just "ok"
```

Because `Nothing` is the value of the type `Maybe a`, `Nothing` 's type is `Maybe Integer` or `Maybe String` , so I think I can specify the type as follows:

```
*Main> return Nothing :: Maybe String
```

But I got an error:

```
    Couldn't match type `Maybe a0' with `[Char]'
Expected type: String
  Actual type: Maybe a0
In the first argument of `return', namely `Nothing'
In the expression: return Nothing :: Maybe String
In an equation for `it': it = return Nothing :: Maybe String
```

I am confused about what is the type signature for that.

Comment: Usually, you don't need to *return* Nothing, at the end of a do block `Nothing` is enough. I mean `do Nothing` is valid.

Comment: You might be looking for something more along the lines of `fail "To err is human" :: Maybe t`, which will result in `Nothing`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between:

```
*Main> return 1 :: Maybe Integer
```

And

```
*Main> return Nothing :: Maybe String
```

Is that `1` has type `Integer`, but `Nothing` has type `Maybe a`. If you want to wrap `Nothing` into another `Maybe` value, you should specify the type for `Nothing` like this:

```
*Main> return Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe String)
Just Nothing
```

Answer (score 11):

In the lines

```
return 1
return "ok"
```

the `return` works inside the `Maybe` monad, so `return = Just` here.

In the line

```
return Nothing :: Maybe String
```

the compiler spots that your code is of the form

```
return ... :: Maybe ...
```

so, once again, `return = Just`. Your code is equivalent to

```
Just Nothing :: Maybe String
```

which is the same as

```
Just (Nothing :: String)
```

but `Nothing` is not a string, it is a `Maybe a` for any `a` -- hence the type error.

You probably are looking for

```
Nothing :: Maybe String -- no return here
```

which works fine.

By the way, you can ask GHCi to give the type for an expression with the `:t` command:

```
> :t return Nothing
Monad m => m (Maybe a)
```

Comment: I personally would typecheck the last expression as `Monad m => m (Maybe a)`. I'm not sure where GHCi infers (m ~ Maybe)